# Unexpected elements in XSLT function result

Tags: xslt-3.0

```
    <xsl:function name="f:members" as="xs:string*">
        <xsl:param name="in" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:param name="grp" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:param name="result" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:param name="state" as="xs:integer"/>"
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="empty($in)">
                <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$state=0">
                <xsl:sequence select="f:leafs(remove($in,1),$grp,$result,1)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$state=1 and not($in[1]=$grp)">
                <xsl:sequence select="f:leafs(remove($in,1),($grp,$in[1]),$result,1)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$state=1 and $in[1]=$grp">
                <xsl:sequence select="f:leafs(remove($in,1),$grp,$result,2)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$state=2 and not($in[1]=$grp)">
                <xsl:sequence select="f:leafs(remove($in,1),$grp,($result,$in[1]),2)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$state=2 and $in[1]=$grp">
                <xsl:sequence select="f:leafs(remove($in,1),$grp,$result,2)"/>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>

'trees','oak1','beech1','beech2',
'oak1','oak-leaf1','oak-leaf2',
'beech1','beach-leaf1','beach-leaf2','beach-leaf5',
'beech2','beach-leaf3','beach-leaf4'
```

Processor: Saxon-HE 9.9.1-5, called from Java via the Saxon API.
Given is a list of groups. The first group covers the names of the following groups. This group of group names ends, when a group name appears.
I reduced my problem to a garden with 3 trees, each has some leafs. Trees group leafs.
Now I want to fill a variable (a basket of leafs) with the group members, the leafs, by calling the recursive function f:members.
f:members has two states: collect the groups, collect the leafs.
Group names are not added to the result.
The recursion terminates when the list is empty.

For the given test data, I expect 7 leafs in the basket.
But I get 22! Lots of empty elements and - surprisingly - elements containing one double-quote. The leafs are also there, at the end.

The complete test stylesheet can be found [here](https://owncloud.august.de/index.php/s/fa5mJnneVNRcQo9) together with the result on my computer.

Where do the extra elements come from?

Answer (score 1):

For some reasons, you have a line `<xsl:param name="state" as="xs:integer"/>"` (note the trailing `"`) in there where you literally output a quote `"` on each call of your function, so I suppose you want to remove that literal quote and simply declare the parameter `<xsl:param name="state" as="xs:integer"/>`.

Comment: Thank you Martin - I've looked at the code for 2 days prior to asking here and did lots of checks. Sometimes one need 4 eyes to find the simplest causes.